# String Array Count

Tags: c

below is my code. i know its a very simple problem but i dont know why this code is not working. i simply want to count number of strings in my array but its always showing me a count 1.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str[]={"Bharti","Bharat","Akas"};
    int a=PalindromeLengthPuzzle(str);
    return 0;
}
int PalindromeLengthPuzzle(char* input1[])
{
    //const char *mystr=input1;
    int i;
    int sarray= sizeof(input1)/sizeof(input1[0]);
    printf("%s",input1[0]);
    //int sarray=sizeof(mystr)/sizeof(mystr[0]);
    //int x=sizeof(mystr[0]);
    printf("%d",sarray);
    //printf("%s",input1[1]);
    /*for( i=0;i<sarray;i++)
    {
    printf("%s",input1[i]);
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the above code is `Bharti1` and it should be 3 instead of 1. Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an array passed to a function as an argument it implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

Thus these three function declarations are equivalent

```
int PalindromeLengthPuzzle(char* input1[3]);
int PalindromeLengthPuzzle(char* input1[]);
int PalindromeLengthPuzzle(char** input1);
```

and declare the same one function.

Within the function the parameter is a local variable of type `char **`

So statement

```
int sarray= sizeof(input1)/sizeof(input1[0]);
```

is equivalent to

```
int sarray= sizeof( char ** )/sizeof( char * );
```

and evaluates to 1.

You should either declare a second parameter that will contain the number of elements in the array or us some sentinel value as for example NULL as the last velement of the array that within the functionto determine the number of elements by using this sentinel.

Here are demonstrated the two approaches

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int PalindromeLengthPuzzle( char* input1[], size_t n )
{
   // ...
}

int main()
{
    char *str[] = { "Bharti", "Bharat", "Akas" };
    int a = PalindromeLengthPuzzle( str , sizeof( str ) / sizeof( *str ) );

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int PalindromeLengthPuzzle( char* input1[] )
{
   // ...
}

int main()
{
    char *str[] = { "Bharti", "Bharat", "Akas", NULL };
    int a = PalindromeLengthPuzzle( str );

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a working example with sentinel

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PalindromeLengthPuzzle( char* input1[] )
{
    while ( *input1 ) puts( *input1++ );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *str[] = { "Bharti", "Bharat", "Akas", NULL };

    PalindromeLengthPuzzle( str );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Bharti
Bharat
Akas
```

Comment: Will this be permissible in my code `while(input1[i]!=NULL) { some logic; i++ ;}` ??

Comment: @G.S Abhaypal Yes, you can check whether the next value is the sentinel.:)

Comment: This is what i got `BhartiBharatAkasÀÁo·àÃo·p°o·d°o·d°o·` , :/ i guess its going in infinite loop , and adding garbage values after actual values.

Comment: @G.S Abhaypal You have to include the last initializer equal to NULL as it is shown in my example. Wait a minute I will provide a working program.

Comment: i did this , `char *mystr[]={input1,NULL};`

Comment: Sorry sorry , actually i was looping through input1 , and i am appending sentinel value in mystr.

Comment: @G.S Abhaypal  See my updated post where there is shown a working example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75490/discussion-between-g-s-abhaypal-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: Thanks for the update , but input is not in my hand. It is dynamic and i have to handle it completely in my function only. So i did following. `char *mystr[]={input1,NULL};` But while iterating , its showing garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str[]={"Bharti","Bharat","Akas"};
    int a=PalindromeLengthPuzzle(str, sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]));
    return 0;
}
int PalindromeLengthPuzzle(char* input1[], int sarray)
{
    //const char *mystr=input1;
    int i;
    printf("%s",input1[0]);
    //int sarray=sizeof(mystr)/sizeof(mystr[0]);
    //int x=sizeof(mystr[0]);
    printf("%d",sarray);
    //printf("%s",input1[1]);
    /*for( i=0;i<sarray;i++)
    {
    printf("%s",input1[i]);
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

Arrays decay into pointers in methods hence you cannot calculate the size inside the function - rather pass the size in function call.

Comment: Actually in the function `PalindromeLengthPuzzle()` i am not suppose to pass anything else. Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: Then make the variable `sarray` Global.